# Test1 & Test2 in the same package, so why do I need import test2? if I don't use import, Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4), It will go wrong

Tags: java

Test1 & Test2 in the same package, so why do I need import test2?

if I don't use import,  Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4), It will go wrong.
 && other question:

```
public void show(final int number){

 }
```

If I use final here, What' this meaning?

```
 package info;
    import info.Test2.Inn;

    public class Test1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int sum = 1;
            Test2 test2 = new Test2(2);
            Test2.Inn inn = test2.new Inn(3);
            Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4);
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                sum = (sum + 1) * 2;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
    class Test2 {
        private int test;

        public Test2(int test) {
            this.test = test;
        }


        class Inn{
            private int inn;

            public Inn(int inn) {
                this.inn = inn;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Members of the inner class are known only within the scope of the inner class and may not be used by the outer class. The Java compiler generates an error message if any code outside of class Test2 attempts to instantiate class Inn. Generalizing, a nested class is no different than any other program element: it is known only within its enclosing scope. Please mention in which class you want to add final method.

Comment: Use Test2.Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same package can only omit the package name.

The whole signature:

```
package_name.Test2.Inn
package_name.Test2
```

->

```
Test2.Inn
Test2
```

If use `Inn` instead of `Test2.Inn`

What if there is a class in same package with name `Inn`?

---

The `final` in method signature means `number` cannot be modified.

So something like `number++` is not allowed in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove import statement as follows

> Test2.Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4);

So, entire code might be looks,

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 1;
        Test2 test2 = new Test2(2);
        Test2.Inn inn = test2.new Inn(3);
        Test2.Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            sum = (sum + 1) * 2;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }


}

class Test2 {
    private int test;

    public Test2(int test) {
        this.test = test;
    }


    class Inn{
        private int inn;

        public Inn(int inn) {
            this.inn = inn;
        }

    }
}
```

Let me show you another case

Make Test2 inner class of the Test1 class

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 1;
        Test2 test2 = new Test2(2);
        Test2.Inn inn = test2.new Inn(3);
        Test2.Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            sum = (sum + 1) * 2;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    class Test2 {
        private int test;

        public Test2(int test) {
            this.test = test;
        }


        class Inn{
            private int inn;

            public Inn(int inn) {
                this.inn = inn;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But the code won't compile yet because you can not access Test2 class in the static method of Test1 class.

So, you can do this

> static class Test2

Now, you can access static member Test2 class of Test1 and its inner class Inn by declaring Test2.Inn

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 1;
        Test2 test2 = new Test2(2);
        Test2.Inn inn = test2.new Inn(3);
        Test2.Inn inn1 = test2.new Inn(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            sum = (sum + 1) * 2;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    static class Test2 {
        private int test;

        public Test2(int test) {
            this.test = test;
        }


        class Inn{
            private int inn;

            public Inn(int inn) {
                this.inn = inn;
            }

        }
    }    
}
```

Then, the above code is a little ugly so, I can finally make my own code

```
import Test1.Test2.Inn;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 1;
        Test2 test2 = new Test2(2);
        Inn inn = new Inn(3);
        Inn inn1 = new Inn(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            sum = (sum + 1) * 2;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    static class Test2 {
        private int test;

        public Test2(int test) {
            this.test = test;
        }


        static class Inn{
            private int inn;

            public Inn(int inn) {
                this.inn = inn;
            }

        }
    }    
}
```

I think it is all about scope or accessibility of class.